# Shuffle file name arguments in zsh

Tags: zsh, filenames, command-line-arguments

Suppose the application can only open files via command line arguments, how would i go about randomizing a list of file names/paths to accomplish this?

I thought this should be fairly easy but apparently spaces make it more complicated than it should be.

---

An example:

> a.mp3 
>   b.mp3 
>   with space.mp3

When i try `$(ls | shuf)` the space is not escaped yielding something like `with space.mp3 b.mp3 a.mp3`.

Using the quote option `-Q` does not help either because the command substitution escapes the quotes resulting in the following: `\"with space.mp3\" \"a.mp3\" \"b.mp3\"`

Similarly the escapes of `-b` get escaped as well: `with\\ space.mp3 a.mp3 b.mp3`

Something like `find`'s `-exec <application> {} \+` without the finding would be perfect...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a zsh-only variant, getting rid of `ls` as well as `shuf`:

```
mplayer *.mp3(oe:REPLY=\$RANDOM:)
```

The Glob Qualifier `o` executes (`e`) the code between both colons (`:`). The code in turn assigns every file a pseudo-random number `$RANDOM`, resulting in an arbitrary order.

To obscure the command a little more, but mainly to save key strokes, you can define a shell function `s`:

```
s() { REPLY=$RANDOM }
mplayer *.mp3(oe:s:)
```

Or, even better, define a  key binding, e.g. for `CTRL+R` for the shuffle part:

```
bindkey -s '^R' '(oe:REPLY=\\$RANDOM:)^M'
```

Now, type only `mplayer *.mp3` followed by `CTRL+R`, and the `(oe:REPLY=\$RANDOM:)` part gets appended and the command line immediately executed (`^M`).

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `ls` at all. Try

```
mplayer "${(f)$(shuf -e *.mp3)}"
```

The problem with `ls` is that it is often aliased to something like `ls --color=always` and in that case prints invisible characters which are not recognized properly by other programs (`shuf` in this example).

Comment: I know that i do not need `ls`, but `ls` is not the problem in any case, the problem is `zsh` escaping characters it should not escape. Also i don't get why anyone would be using `color=always` instead of `auto`...

Comment: Sometimes "always" can be really useful, e.g. when there is a lot of files in directory: `cd /usr/bin; ls -l | less`.

Comment: I presume you mean `less -R`, otherwise the colour chars are encoded. Supposed one could use it for that, i usually execute `ls` and scroll the terminal itself.

Comment: @H.B.: Sorry to say that, but [you shouldn't parse the the output of ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)... so I would identify indeed the `ls` as the problem.

Comment: @mpy: Not buying it, `ls -b` works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think i finally figured out a method: `${(f)"$(ls | shuf)"}`

Breakdown:

`ls | shuf`: Shuffle files/dirs as expected. 
`"$(...)"`: The quotes maintain the output as it is, including newlines. 
`${(f)...}`: Splits the result of the expansion at newlines yielding an array of the file/dir names.

---

`"${(f)$(ls | shuf)}"` works as well, `${(f)$(ls | shuf)}`, does not.